# is the a possiblity to call the x.Enter which is automatically executed a second time with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

The question is how to execute the function a second time with different arguments.

```
// my class
        let x = new class CB {

            constructor() {
                this.onEnter = function(callback) {
                    this.user = { user: 'Peter', isMember: true };
                    callback(this.user);
                }
            }
        }


//my call    

        x.onEnter(function(user) {
            console.log(user.user + " listed!");
        });

// How to do a second call....how with different parameters every time?
        console.log(x.onEnter);
    ...
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you did it the first time. You just pass a different function.

```
    x.onEnter(function(user) {
        console.log(user.user + " listed!");
    });
    x.onEnter(function(user) {
        console.log(user.user + " twisted!");
    });
```